# Injecting variable into attribute in MPTS

Tags: javascript

I tried to make template using [MPTS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mpts-core) and it works for this h2, but I cannot inject attribute for img

```
<div>
   <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
   <img src="user.avatar" class="avatar" />
</div>
```

I also tried `<img src="{{user.avatar}}" class="avatar" />` but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To inject a variable as an attribute you need to ommit quotes. Quotes means to threat it as a string.

```
<img src=user.avatar class="avatar" />
```